# What means of resurrection does the Implosion spell prevent?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, resurrection

[This new (and therefore spoiler-filled) strip](https://www.giantitp.com/comics/oots1210.html) of The Order of the Stick makes the claim that [Implosion](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/implosion.htm) has been used to prevent resurrection, presumably from the party's Wizard's access to [Limited Wish](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/limitedWish.htm). This got me thinking, what means of resurrection does Implosion actually prevent?

At first I thought that it might prevent [Raise Dead](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/raiseDead.htm) and not [Resurrection](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/resurrection.htm), but I've recently noticed that Implosion's text is not explicit about whether or not it destroys bodies.

Comment: Perhaps Burlew mixed up the descriptions of [*destruction*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#destruction) and *implosion*?

Comment: Implosion also says one can target a creature only once.  While talking is a free action in 3.5e, the number of panels (and squelchy sound effects) suggest it works a little differently in OOTS.  Some folks [here](https://forums.giantitp.com/showthread.php?617254-OOTS-1210-The-Discussion-Thread) seem to think so as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implosion does not prevent any form of resurrection. Instead, its niche is that it circumvents death ward by lacking the [death](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#deathAttacks) descriptor. Although it slays its target, it is not a death spell.

Comment: Ironically, the [death] descriptor **does** prevent *raise dead*, so by lacking it, *implosion* is actually worse at this particular thing than most insta-death effects. Of course, by the time you can cast a 9th-level spell like *implosion*, *resurrection* has long been available anyway, so there’s little reason to be concerned about *raise dead* specifically, and bypassing *death ward* is far more valuable.

Comment: @KRyan I suppose it depends on if you count an imploded body as whole. If it is, then it can be repaired by *Raise Dead*, otherwise the spell might have some trouble with that particular aspect

Answer (score 0):

It might be more of the fact that the body has so little left to resurrect that it's easy to hide/remove the rest of the body. It may also just be a misinterpretation on the part of the author. 1210 strips in could make it easy to forget such details specially since the author doesn't play dnd that much any more according to some old interview/blog post.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. This answer seems entirely speculative, and seems like more of a comment on/addendum to Wannabe Warlock's answer, as it doesn't directly answer the question asked. You may want to edit it to more clearly do so first, before addressing how it might be interpreted to work in such a manner.